# SQLPLus Decode if value is not null

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a sqlplus script and if a variable is not null then I want to execute a script and pass the value. If it is null then I want to execute a different script. I have the following:

```
col scr new_value script
set term off
select decode('&partitions', 'true', 'CreateTablesPartitions', 'CreateTables') scr from   dual;
set term on
@@&script &partitions
```

Which checks if the variable partitions is true then execute CreateTablePartitions. How do I check if the variable partitions is null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just add null and the value to decode to in your decode string.

```
select decode('&partitions', 'true', 'CreateTablesPartitions',
              null, 'itsnull', 'CreateTables') scr 
from   dual;
```

so if its null, then the result will be `itsnull`

Answer (score 2):

You can just include `null` as a recognised value in your decode:

```
col scr new_value script
set term off
set verify off
select decode('&partitions', null, 'CreateTables',
    'CreateTablesPartitions') as scr from dual;
set term on
@@&script &partitions
```

... which will run `CreateTables` if the entered `partitions` value is null.

But, because you have `termout off`, you won't see the prompt for the value. You might want to use positional variables (`&1` etc.) depending on how you're intending to call this, but assuming you do want to be prompted at run-time, you can either leave `termout on` and add `noprint` to the `column` command (`col scr new_value script noprint`), which will give some blank lines in the output; or set `partitions` earlier. You can't use `define` though because that won't like a null value.

The cleanest approach may be to use [`accept`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACHDBHG) with its own prompt:

```
accept partitions prompt "Enter partitions: "

col scr new_value script noprint
set verify off
set term off
select decode('&partitions', null, 'CreateTables',
    'CreateTablesPartitions') as scr from dual;
set term on
@@&script &partitions
```

With simple dummy scripts to call, e.g. `CreateTables.sql`:

```
prompt In CreateTables
```

... and `CreateTablesPartitions`:

```
prompt In CreateTablesPartitions with passed value "&1"
```

... this gives:

```
Enter partitions: 
In CreateTables
```

... and:

```
Enter partitions: Test
In CreateTablesPartitions with passed value "Test"
```